# React - Where to unit test state change when parent component passes method as prop: parent or child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to figure out the best way to unit test the following situation

- Parent class component `App` holds the state of number of `attendees` as well a method `handleAttendeesChange()` to update the state
- `App` renders a child component `Attendees` and passes it 2 props: `currentCount` and `onValueChange`

The question is: do I test that the state is changing properly in **App.tsx** or **Attendees.tsx**?
I've seen examples where I should test the state change in the parent component but those examples show that the parent component displays the value in the DOM instead of the child.

Code is below

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { FC, Component } from 'react';
import {Attendees} from './Attendees';


interface AppState {
  attendees: number
}
export default class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAttendeesChange = this.handleAttendeesChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      attendees: 0
    };
  }

  handleAttendeesChange(value: number) {
    this.setState({ attendees: this.state.attendees + value});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Parent Component</h1>
        <Attendees currentCount={this.state.attendees} onValueChange={this.handleAttendeesChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Attendees.tsx**

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

type AttendeesProps = {
  currentCount: number,
  onValueChange: (value: number) => void
}

export const Attendees:FC<AttendeesProps> = ({ currentCount, onValueChange }) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <button data-testid="countUp" onClick={() => onValueChange(1)}>
          Up
        </button >
        <button data-testid="countDown" onClick={() => onValueChange(-1)}>
          Down
        </button >
        <p data-testid="currentCount">
          {currentCount}
        </p>
        
      </div>
    
  )
}
```

Here's what I am currently testing in Attendeees.test.tsx using react-testing-library

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
// import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import {Attendees} from './Attendees';
let container: any = null;
beforeEach(() => {
  // setup a DOM element as a render target
  container = document.createElement("Main");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  // cleanup on exiting
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});
it("Attendees should respond to callback props", () => {
  const onValueChange = jest.fn();
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Attendees currentCount={0} onValueChange={onValueChange} />, container)

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('countUp'))
  expect(onValueChange).toBeCalledWith(1);
  expect(onValueChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(getByTestId('currentCount').textContent).toBe('1');

})
```

Comment: I would say if the state is in the parent then a unit test covering a state update should be against the parent component. Unit tests for the child component should probably cover just the callback functions. Though it seems you have a tight coupling between these two components that it probably doesn't matter and could be done in a single unit test suite.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but may help someone having same question.

*"Do I test that the state is changing properly in App.tsx or Attendees.tsx?"*

We don't have to test whether `setState` is working properly or not. However, if we want to test that the updated count is displayed in the Attendees component, we could test it in `App.test.tsx`, because that is where the state resides.

### Couple more ideas about the tests

We don't have to create a container in `beforeEach` and then remove it in `afterEach`. The `react-testing-library` takes care of it.

Here's my version of the Attendees.test.tsx:

```js
// Attendees.test.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Attendees } from './Attendees';

describe('Attendees component', () => {
  it('should respond to Up button click', () => {
    const onValueChange = jest.fn();
    render(<Attendees currentCount={0} onValueChange={onValueChange} />);

    // Don't have to use data-testid all the time. Here's another way
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('up', { exact: false }));
    expect(onValueChange).toBeCalledWith(1);
    expect(onValueChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should respond to Down button click', () => {
    const onValueChange = jest.fn();
    render(<Attendees currentCount={0} onValueChange={onValueChange} />);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('down', { exact: false }));
    expect(onValueChange).toBeCalledWith(-1);
    expect(onValueChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

I would place the test that checks for the current count display in the App.test.tsx:

```js
// App.test.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

describe('App component', () => {

  it('should display increased attendee count when the Up button is clicked', () => {
    render(<App />);

    // Sometimes it may be a good idea to ensure that the precondition is true
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('current-attendee-count').textContent).toBe('0');

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('up', { exact: false }));

    expect(screen.getByLabelText('current-attendee-count').textContent).toBe('1');
  });
});
```

#### Note

The examples above were tested using React v17.0.1, and @testing-library/react v11.2.3.

Comment: hi antony, i've a structure where the input is within the parent component, and the effect where the input is changed happens on the child component, jest.fn() can't be mocked the same way as it's not a prop, i've noticed this pattern on many components and it's seems the tests are lost this way, and in the docs they pointed not to care much about function implementation by this doesn't seem right ? , i'm i going the right direction.

Comment: Hi Mohab, when the documentation says do not test function implementation, it means that we should avoid testing the private or helper functions in the component. It is good to test the UI behavior instead of testing the internal functions in the component. For your input in the parent component, you may want to fire the event in the parent component to change the input, and then test the UI state change (the end effect caused by the input change). Hope it helps. Pls let me know if my answer is not clear.

Comment: "the end effect caused by the input change", this happens in the child component, you mean i should render the child as well in the parent component tests?

Comment: Hi Mohab, thank you for asking. Could you please explain how the change in the parent reaches the child? Via props or some other way?

Comment: Antony, thank you for taking the time, so the state is within the parent, the event (say click) happens in a child component (the button is within the child), the function is passed as a prop from the parent to the child, when the event takes place what is changed is in the parent component (the final effect), so when i test the parent isolated from it's child (recommended by the testing lib) i can't invoke the event, and when i test the child i can't see the final effect because it happens in the parent.

Comment: If you want to simply test that the child invokes the callback function prop from the parent, then you can just pass a `jest.fn()` mock as the child prop and test that it is called. The `Attendees.test.tsx` example in my answer shows how to do this.
But if you want to test that the whole UI effect from child to parent is working as expected, then you have to mount both the parent and the child. This approach is shown in the `App.test.tsx` example in my answer. The example tests if the counter is increased from 0 to 1. Your case may be to check for something else, but the concept is the same.